# Angle between vector and one vector of general orthonormal basis

Tags: geometry

My question asks to consider a vector a=2e+3f+6g where {e,f,g} is an orthonormal basis. I am then asked to show that the angle between a and g belongs to the interval (π/6, π/4). I can show this easily using scalar product if the basis is the standard orthonormal basis, however i am unsure how to prove this for all orthonormal bases. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the angle between vectors of all orthonormal bases is such that their dot product is zero. In 3 dimensions, you can rotate any basis around the origin in a way that will get you the standard orthonormal basis. With one little caveat, you might have to multiply one of the basic vectors by minus one (Think of the physics trick with three fingers).

Thus, having $a$ expressed in terms of your orthonormal basis, you do not have to worry about its orientation as you can imagine a rotation that takes one basis to another (the point here is that the formula for angle gives you RELATIVE angle between the vectors). The only thing you need to check then is what happens when you take $-e_1$ in the standard basis instead of $e_1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the $\cos$ of the angle between $a$ and $g$ is $\frac{\langle a,g\rangle}{\|a\|\cdot\|g\|}$. Now why is the numerator $6$ and the denominator $7$?